# How to "include" members in an Array of pointers in Parse?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

- I have a parseObject called Items. Inside this class there is a pointer to another ParseObject called Shop. This holds the shop details of that particular item.
- My User class has an array of pointers that point to Items.

[image]

- When I retrieve this array, I'm not getting the Shop details. I'm guessing because I don't have it "included".

Currently I'm retrieving the array from the user class this way:

```
 ArrayList<Item> RecentlyViewed = (ArrayList<Item>) ParseUser.getCurrentUser.get("RecentViewed");
```

I pin this list. In offline mode, this gets me null, saying that that shop doesn't exist in the offline cache.

```
RecentlyViewed.get(0).get("Shop").getString("Name");
```

How do I include the shop details when I'm retrieving the array of Items so that I can access them?

Comment: This makes no sense, can you give us the code as a example? Or clearly define what you require.

Comment: @TejjD I sort of simplified it more. I couldn't show the code as an example, because there is a lot of boilerplate and what not, it'd be more difficult to explain. But I hope this helps.

Comment: From what I can see, it might only be an issue with how you are parsing your data in. The other thing is you are constantly referring to "pointers" which makes it seem like something to do with C++

Comment: In the Parse docs, they're called pointers. In the image of parse browser I've shown also says "Pointers".

Answer (score 0):

You are storing a list of Pointer objects in an `Array` field. `Include` works only on fields of type Pointer which points to only a single item. The best way to have an array of pointers in Parse is to use a `Relation`.

Comment: Hmm, no way to do it through arrays? Because all I wanted was to store items in a list. And an Array feels so simplified to accomplish this task. It's just retrieving the inner pointers of those array elements that I'm having issue with.

guess I have to rewrite the relationships.

Comment: Array is not a good choice for storing Pointer objects. Working with a Relation is far more easier